# MongoDB Compass using docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, ip, mongodb-compass

I'm trying to manage my MongoDB databases through the GUI interface, but I don't how to set up it correctly. At the moment I'm using docker to set up all the necessary and I'm connecting through the command

`mongo --host "localhost:27017,localhost:27016"`.

Now, when I open MongoDB Compass, it ask me for a string of this format:
[image]

How can I format my IP correctly?

Comment: Did you try `mongodb://localhost:27017`?

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As @super said, the answer was just `mongodb://localhost:27017`